# Why there is no Velocity after spring-boot-starter-parent 1.4.7?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to upgrade my spring-boot-starter-parent from 1.4.2 to latest:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

But this won't work any more:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-velocity</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I found that after 1.4.7, the velocity package is no longer included in the parent. How to deal with this? Can I suspend 'velocity' dependency after upgrading the dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.0 depends on Spring Framework 5.0. Which dropped support for Velocity. Hence in Spring Boot 2 there is no more support for Velocity.

```
Dropped support: Portlet, Velocity, JasperReports, XMLBeans, JDO, Guava.
```

If you really need Velocity, Recommendation: Stay on Spring Framework 4.3.x for those if needed.

Please read [What's new Spring Framework 5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#removed-packages-classes-and-methods)

**Removed Packages, Classes and Methods**

> ```
> Package beans.factory.access (BeanFactoryLocator mechanism).
> Package jdbc.support.nativejdbc (NativeJdbcExtractor mechanism).
> Package mock.staticmock removed from spring-aspects module.
> No support for AnnotationDrivenStaticEntityMockingControl anymore.
> Packages web.view.tiles2 and orm.hibernate3/hibernate4 dropped.
> Minimum requirement: Tiles 3 and Hibernate 5 now.
> Dropped support: Portlet, Velocity, JasperReports, XMLBeans, JDO, Guava.
> Recommendation: Stay on Spring Framework 4.3.x for those if needed.
> Many deprecated classes and methods removed across the codebase.
> A few compromises made for commonly used methods in the ecosystem.
> ```

Comment: So I can remove velocity?